# iOS 5 send Direct messages to multiple twitter accounts

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878512/using-ios-5-twitter-api-to-send-private-message) url for sending DM Direct messages to twitter account programatically

So I would like to know that , can we send Direct messages to multiple twitter accounts

Kindly let me know your thoughts

Comment: Sure, send multiple DMs. Then wait and see if Twitter suspends you for spamming.